# How to center MJML column while using text-align:left

Tags: html-email, mjml

I'm trying to center a mjml container but assign the text to left-adjustment.

I've been playing around with `align="center"` and `text-align` in various tags, but I can't seem to find a solution.

```
<mjml>
  <mj-body>
    <mj-section>
      <mj-column border="1px solid black">
        <mj-text align="center">
          <div style="text-align: left !important;">Text should be in middle of container<br>but left-adjusted.</br>
          </div>
        </mj-text>
      </mj-column>
    </mj-section>
  </mj-body>
</mjml>
```

In my sample code, using `align="center"` moves the enter text in the middle of the screen (great!) but there's nothing that forces the text to left-adjustment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's a little unclear what you want, but I've got a centered container with left-aligned text with the following code:

```html
    <mjml>
      <mj-body>
        <mj-section>
          <mj-column border="1px solid black" align="center">
              <mj-text style="text-align: left;">Text should be in middle of container<br>but left-adjusted.</br>
              </mj-text>
          </mj-column>
        </mj-section>
      </mj-body>
    </mjml>
```

The key was not to put the mj-text as center aligned, as that's the text part.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 2 columns and you want them to be aligned central with each other you can must set the vertical-align on both the columns.

```
<mj-section>
  <mj-group>
  <mj-column vertical-align="middle">
    <mj-image
      width="200px"
      src="some-img-url.png"
    ></mj-image>
  </mj-column>

  <mj-column vertical-align="middle">
    <mj-text align="left">Some text</mj-text>
    <mj-text font-weight="100" align="left">Some more text</mj-text>
  </mj-column>
    </mj-group>
</mj-section>
```